# how Apache Commons StringUtils.repeat() works and why it works in this way?

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

I just start using apache-commons library today and find interesting the way they wrote `repeat()`

here is the source code of the method:

```
public static String repeat(final String str, final int repeat) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (repeat <= 0) {
        return EMPTY;
    }
    final int inputLength = str.length();
    if (repeat == 1 || inputLength == 0) {
        return str;
    }
    if (inputLength == 1 && repeat <= PAD_LIMIT) {
        return repeat(str.charAt(0), repeat);
    //here the author use FOR loop with char[]
    }

    final int outputLength = inputLength * repeat;
    switch (inputLength) {
        case 1 :
            return repeat(str.charAt(0), repeat);
        case 2 :
            final char ch0 = str.charAt(0);
            final char ch1 = str.charAt(1);
            final char[] output2 = new char[outputLength];
            for (int i = repeat * 2 - 2; i >= 0; i--, i--) {
                output2[i] = ch0;
                output2[i + 1] = ch1;
            }
            return new String(output2);
        default :
            final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(outputLength);
            for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
                buf.append(str);
            }
            return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

I am just wondering for which reason(s) they divide the repeat into several cases ? Is there anything relate to the performance?
If I was asked to write 'repeat()', I will simply use a FOR loop with `append()`

I would like to know what I can learn from looking at how the author wrote the code.

Comment: I'm sure it's performance. Most people would just write a stringbuffer with a for loop.

Comment: Micro-optimization. If `str` has length of one or two characters, a different, faster pattern is used.

Comment: @Bubletan would you please explain why when the length is 1or2, a different pattern can be faster?

Comment: @pledez The different pattern might be faster for other lengths too, but there's no point in writing it separately for all of the different cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the authors have optimised the method for a couple of use cases they think/know are common: one- and two-character input strings.

This is a good example why it's beneficial to use a framework (such as Commons Lang) for this sort of string manipulation; the API will hide the implementation details which are not always idiomatic or easy to read to you or your colleagues, but may improve performance.

Comment: with your answer and @Bubletan's comments, I think, maybe from a statistical perspective, the repeat of one or two characters are most frequently used by programmer so the author specifically wrote these two optimized cases.

Comment: @pledez Or rather that's what the author assumed.